# JAXB and a stack of subclasses produces wrong json

Tags: json, jaxb, moxy

Is it possible to achieve un-/marshalling of a class structure that utilizes nesting of several `abstract` classes?
Given a class structure like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Animal {}
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal {}
public class Tiger extends Mammal {}
public class Elephant extends Mammal {}
```

The `@XmlRootElement`ed `Zoo` class has a list of animals:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "animals")
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "elephant", type = Elephant.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "tiger", type = Tiger.class)
})
private List<Animal> animals;
```

I think you get the idea ... the XML for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<zoo>
   <animals>
      <tiger>
         <name>Richard</name>
         <furry>true</furry>
      </tiger>
      <elephant>
         <name>Otis</name>
         <furry>false</furry>
      </elephant>
      <tiger>
         <name>Kirk</name>
         <furry>true</furry>
      </tiger>
   </animals>
</zoo>
```

This looks fine, cool.
Now the JSON ...

```
 {
    "animals" : {
       "tiger" : [ {
          "name" : "Richard",
          "furry" : true
       }, {
          "name" : "Kirk",
          "furry" : true
       } ],
       "elephant" : [ {
          "name" : "Otis",
          "furry" : false
       } ]
    }
 }
```

Why does it subgroup the `Mammal` class objects in JSON?

Im using EclipseLink MOXy 2.6 for marshalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

MOXy groups the keys `tiger` and `elephant` to avoid repeating them.

---

### UPDATE #1

> So it not possible to get a JSON like { 'animals': [ {'@type':
>   'tiger'}, {'@type': elephant'}, ... ] }?

Yes it's possible, you just need to map it that way:

**Zoo**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Zoo {

    private List<Animal> animals;

}
```

**Animal**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlSeeAlso({Elephant.class, Tiger.class})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Animal {

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX, "@");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Zoo.class}, properties);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource json = new StreamSource("src/forum19384491/input.json");
        Zoo zoo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Zoo.class).getValue();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(zoo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.json/Output**

```
{
   "animals" : [ {
      "@type" : "tiger"
   }, {
      "@type" : "elephant"
   }, {
      "@type" : "tiger"
   } ]
}
```

### UPDATE #2

If you want to keep your current XML representation and just change the JSON representation you could use MOXy's external mapping document extension (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html)

**Mapping Document (oxm.xml)**

We will use MOXy's external mapping document to change the mapping for the `animals` field on the `Zoo` class.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum19384491">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Zoo">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="animals"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we create 2 instances of `JAXBContext` on the same domain model.  The one for JSON leverages an external mapping document to customize the mapping.  `input.xml` is the XML document from your question.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext xmlJC = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = xmlJC.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum19384491/input.xml");
        Zoo zoo = (Zoo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(4);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum19384491/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX, "@");
        JAXBContext jsonJC = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Zoo.class}, properties);

        Marshaller marshaller = jsonJC.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(zoo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
{
   "animals" : [ {
      "@type" : "tiger",
      "name" : "Richard",
      "furry" : true
   }, {
      "@type" : "elephant",
      "name" : "Otis",
      "furry" : false
   }, {
      "@type" : "tiger",
      "name" : "Kirk",
      "furry" : true
   } ]
}
```

Comment: So it not possible to get a JSON like `{ 'animals': [ {'@type': 'tiger'}, {'@type': elephant'}, ... ] }`?